# MySQLSyntaxErrorException 'OPTION SQL_SELECT_LIMIT=DEFAULT'

Tags: mysql, spring-boot, quartz-scheduler, mysql-connector

Using mysql-connector-java-5.1.44-bin.jar and mysql version = 5.7.23 Using Spring Boot, the scheduler throws this error when app starts

```
o.s.scheduling.quartz.LocalDataSourceJobStore - Failed to override connection auto commit/transaction isolation.
    com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLSyntaxErrorException: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'OPTION SQL_SELECT_LIMIT=DEFAULT' at line 1
            at sun.reflect.GeneratedConstructorAccessor174.newInstance(Unknown Source)
            at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
            at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
            at com.mysql.jdbc.Util.handleNewInstance(Util.java:409)
            at com.mysql.jdbc.Util.getInstance(Util.java:384)
            at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:1054)
            at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.checkErrorPacket(MysqlIO.java:3562)
            at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.checkErrorPacket(MysqlIO.java:3494)
            at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.sendCommand(MysqlIO.java:1960)
            at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.sqlQueryDirect(MysqlIO.java:2114)
            at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.execSQL(ConnectionImpl.java:2690)
            at com.mysql.jdbc.StatementImpl.executeSimpleNonQuery(StatementImpl.java:1545)
            at com.mysql.jdbc.StatementImpl.executeQuery(StatementImpl.java:1447)
            at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.getTransactionIsolation(ConnectionImpl.java:3262)
            at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariProxyConnection.getTransactionIsolation(HikariProxyConnection.java)
            at org.quartz.impl.jdbcjobstore.AttributeRestoringConnectionInvocationHandler.setTransactionIsolation(AttributeRestoringConnectionInvocationHandler.java:108)
            at org.quartz.impl.jdbcjobstore.AttributeRestoringConnectionInvocationHandler.invoke(AttributeRestoringConnectionInvocationHandler.java:68)
```

Comment: Are you sure about the version of mysql-connector-java? The error suggests you're using a version older than [5.1.20, the version that fixed the issue](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/relnotes/connector-j/5.1/en/news-5-1-20.html) with outdated `SET OPTION` syntax. Perhaps you have an older jar in your classpath?

Comment: Besides that, I would recommend to get rid of all MySQL Connector/J versions 5.1.*. Upgrade to the latest MySQL Connector/J 8.0.

Comment: @BillKarwin This issue happens when there is high traffic, otherwise this error doesn't show, Any idea why this error happens only when it's high traffic?

Comment: You haven't answered the question about the version of the connector.

Comment: @BillKarwin mysql-connector-java-5.1.45-bin.jar

Comment: I see in your exception stack trace: `at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.getTransactionIsolation(ConnectionImpl.java:3262)` but in both 5.1.44 and 5.1.45, code line 3262 is not inside the `getTransactionIsolation()` method. This makes me think you have some different version of the jar on your classpath. In some older versions of Connector/J, line 3262 is inside that method. It varies by release version, because of course they change the code in every release.

Comment: I searched several versions of the code, and I found that only MySQL Connector/J 5.1.12 has code that could match the stack trace you posted. That is, on line 3262, it's inside method `getTransactionIsolation()` and on that line it calls `executeQuery()`. See https://github.com/mysql/mysql-connector-j/blob/5.1.12/src/com/mysql/jdbc/ConnectionImpl.java#L3262

Comment: @BillKarwin Thanks, found some old versions of connector, that was the root cause

Answer (score 1):

From the comments above, the problem turned out to be that an older version of the MySQL Connector/J was unexpectedly present. The Java CLASSPATH found the older version first.

Supporting [my longstanding rule about Java](https://twitter.com/billkarwin/status/809491612434767872):

[image]